# Getting the list of files from a network folder

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble accessing the network folder from which I would like to copy certain files. I have put together the following code, which for now only prints out the specific files created today.

The issue I'm having is accessing the network folder, with the regular file path it works perfectly, but when I swap it for the network mapped folder it crashes.

```
Sub NetworkFiles()
        Dim n As String, msg As String, d As Date
        msg = ""
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set fils = FSO.GetFolder("\\corp-server\HostingFolder").Files '("C:\FILES") works perfectly
        For Each fil In fils

            n = fil.name
            n = Left(n, 24)
            d = fil.DateLastModified   'DateCreated

            If n = "FILE_CHARACTERS_ARE_RANDOM_AFTER_THIS_POINT" Then
                If d >= Date Then
                    msg = msg & n & vbTab & d & vbCrLf
                End If
            End If
        Next fil
        If msg = "" Then
            MsgBox "No new files"
        Else
            MsgBox msg
        End If
        Set FSO = Nothing
    End Sub
```

***SOLVED*** - loops extremely quickly through an entire folder with 5k+ files

***ANSWER***

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

    Dim file As Variant
    Dim fso As Object

    Source = "\\networkpath\test" 
    file = Dir(Source)
    destloc = "C:\test\folder"


    msg = ""

    While (file <> "")

        If InStr(file, "TEST_partOfTheFileString" & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")) > 0 Then

            FileCopy Source & file, destloc & file
            msg = msg & file & vbCrLf

        End If
        file = Dir

    Wend

    MsgBox msg & "Files Copied"

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it crashes"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Nope, no error message, literally crashes, stops working and I have to force close Excel

Comment: How many files are in the folder? Not only the ones you see with windows explorer also the hidden ones!

Comment: About 1500 files, each file on average has 500kb, and every 15/20 min additional files are uploaded/created... I thought  the issue was potentially the way I try to access the network folder

Comment: Your code is working fine for me, so difficult to tell what the problem is, at least for me. 1500 files should be no problem ... but I only have around 100 files in the folder I tested.

Comment: Hmm, it may be the PC.... Thank you for your help, at least I know the code is working :D

Comment: The issue may be at the string length as MsgBox is limited to 1024 chars. Though it should not crash... Or you could put some checkpoints in there (`Debug.Print`) like before `For each` and after `msg = msg &...` Or you can try the `Dir` function.

Comment: well, it shouldn't be a problem, because the message box will show 6 lines at most, and when I run it with my test file path it works... the issue is that it is a network folder, and I just realized it is an FTP network folder if that makes a difference :/

Comment: UPDATE after a while. the code above works perfectly. The issue was that the folder it was accessing had way to many files to check which would eventually freeze Excel... Solution posted above

Comment: solution should go as answer

Comment: @Mr.Riply- if you have answered the question, please place it in the answer box, then mark as solved